# Windows Explorer View Option via PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell, powershell-5.0

We would like to apply some Explorer folder settings to our user profiles where the following options are set

View: Details
Columns: Name, Date Mondified, Type, Size, Path
Sort By: Date Modified
ColumnWidth:
Name - 600
Path - 600
Rest to autofit
This should be applied to all folders, including Mapped Drives, and sub folders etc.

I have been unable to find anything that will help me set the above for all users either via Registry or via commandline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pick a machine that has not been made, and use the Sysinternals tools, to monitor registry change, make the changes via the Explorer GUI on the host, save off those changes to use in your code.

Comment: Thank You but that seems to be impossible to do because there are many registry changes for each setting that you apply what I did instead was set up the View's as I wanted for each type/group of folder like Documents, Downloads, General, etc. and then I used the "Apply to All Folders" option then used the "Backup And Restore Folder View Settings" from Tenforums.com user Brink. and created a PowerShell script that does the import of the registry keys and I think this is a much better way of doing things than looking at a billion registry key items which will not always work.

Comment: reference to the forum: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/17777-backup-restore-folder-view-settings-windows-10-a.html

Comment: I'll be posting an ansewr for you soon. Been busy. Is your concern primarily file system folders? Those are easy enough. Search Results & Libraries are sligthly more complex. Are you familiar with the _**Arrange-by**_ options in Libraries (right-click in background). Are you OK with the default view of virtual folders like Quick Access, This PC, and Network?

Comment: Are these multiple existing users that should have existing saved views deleted? New users being created?Also, there is no true "Autofit" spicification for column width. There is only default or specifed width.

Comment: Hi Keith, great to see you here, I actually took inspiration from your posts in other forums, but I just couldn't make it work. so I found the easiest solution, I set the layouts according to our requirements in a clean profile, then set each type of folder [general documents, downloads, pictures etc.] and then I set apply to all folder use the script above to export it to a shared folder and created a logon script that imports those reg files.

Comment: For Search Results, I have created an AutoIt script that conforms the view to our standards. basically the same as the OT.